# Parse an output of a command to disconnect a remote desktop session

Tags: windows, windows-8, batch, batch-file

```
qwinsta administrator | findstr Administrator
```

Gives output as

```
>rdp-tcp#26        Administrator             2  Active
```

I need to get only the SESSIONNAME i.e. "rdp-tcp#26" and use in next command as

```
tscon SESSIONNAME /dest:console
```

the variable %sessionname% is not helping so please do not give those solutions.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hint [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Answer (score 1):

I need to get `rdp-tcp#26` and use in next command as

```
tscon SESSIONNAME /dest:console
```

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1" %%i in (`qwinsta administrator ^| findstr Administrator`) do (
  set _temp=%%i
  set sessionname=%_temp:~1%
  )
tscon %sessionname% /dest:console
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).